# When I click on the picture this image opens as a popup but I want to show me another picture not the same picture

Tags: javascript, popup

```
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a  caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
      modal.style.display = "block";
      modalImg.src =this.src;
      captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
```

like this :
[image]

Comment: Please click the `<>` button in the editor and create a [mcve] - It is not clear what you mean by "show me another picture"

Comment: We prefer to have the code here in the question since the link can change. but I still do not understand what you mean by "show me another picture" Some random image?

Comment: like this when click in the image show same image as popup i want to show another image(https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img)

Comment: i add the same code in the link (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal_img) to my website

Answer (score 1):

Add a data attribute to the image tag

```
<img id="myImg" data-src="bigimage.png" src="smallimage.png" alt="This is the caption" />
```

and change the code like this:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a  caption
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  // modalImg.src = this.src;
  modalImg.src = this.getAttribute("data-src");
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
```